# Are Traits good or bad?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, traits, pharo

This is an open-ended question, but I would like to solicit some opinions from the SO community on Traits; do you think Traits in Squeak/Pharo are a good thing, or should you stay away from them and use composition and delegation instead? I ask because while I know how to use them (thanks to the Pharo book), I am not really sure how acceptable it is to use them or where it is OK to use them and where it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

I do not like traits because they introduce strong dependencies into code. These dependencies can be obvious (a class that imports a trait, a trait that expects methods), but also very subtle (a trait that shadows super methods/instance variables). Furthermore there is no adequate tool support for traits.

In my experience *delegation* gives a much better and more reusable design in a dynamically typed object-oriented language like Smalltalk.

Answer (score 2):

Things have their pros and cons. Lukas rightly mentions many of the cons:

- Introduce strong dependencies into code.
- no adequate tool support.

While the second may go away some day, the first will not.

The purpose of traits is to prevent code duplication that occurs, when two classes that don't share a superclass other than Object, share an instance method. Now, sometimes delegation can fix that, but oftentimes it cannot. So, the pro of traits is:

- Reduced code duplication.

My verdict here is that the disadvantages overweigh. I think that, today and forever, code duplication is bound to occur. And when delegation won't do, I can even imagine that code duplication isn't all that harmful, as it often precedes the divergent evolution of the copied code snippets.

[I think, the best thing to do, as of today, is to keep automated track of code duplication, and always monitor when one end changes while the other doesn't. I'm currently writing a tool that'll keep track of such links, even across repositories. I'll report on it in my blog when it's ready.](http://smalltalkthoughts.blogspot.com/)